# Promise for request/response with timeout

Tags: ecmascript-6, promise, timeout

Below is a piece of code that uses **a promise for sending a request** to a server, and to **wait for an answer**. Under normal conditions the server will always respond immediately,

But of course you don't want your code to be stuck forever if a response is missed (e.g. a network issue). So for that reason, **it needs a timeout** as well.

I usually write this as follows. But it takes quiet a lot of code. Any sugestions ?

```
new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  // the promise is resolved when a predefined response is received.
  const listener = (msg) => {
    const { command } = msg;
    if (command === "pong") resolve();
  };

  try {
    this.addListener(listener);

    // write the command
    this.sendMessage( { command: "ping" });

    // there should be an answer within x seconds
    await new Promise(() => setTimeout(reject, timeout));
  }
  finally {
    this.removeListener(listener);
  }
}
```

I have been using this as a pattern for nodejs, angular and react code.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Next time, don't leave anything out. Not a good tactic at Code Review.

Comment: @Mast, So, yeah, so we leave the bug in it ? - And I make a duplicate question without the bug ? Is that what you are proposing (it seems kind of silly).

Comment: That wouldn't be a duplicate question, but a follow-up. It might be silly, but the alternative is creating a mess of no-longer applicable answers to multiple states of the same question. We can't have that.

Answer (score 2):

`await` is only applicable in `async` functions. The executor function passed to `Promise` constructor at the code at the question is not defined as `async`.

The second `Promise` constructor is not necessary. `resolve` and `reject` defined at the single `Promise` executor can be used.

Include `.catch()` or function at second parameter of `.then()` chained to `Promise` constructor to avoid `Uncaught in Promise` error and handle potential error within `Promise` constructor function body.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const complete = () => !clearTimeout(time) 
      && this.removeListener(listener);
    const listener = ({command}) => command === "pong" 
      && !complete() && resolve();
    this.addListener(listener);
    this.sendMessage({ command: "ping" });
    const time = setTimeout(() => !complete() && reject(), timeout);
  } catch (e) {
      throw e
  }
})
// handle resolved `Promise`, handle error
.then(() => {}, e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: just for clarity, I also added the wrapping function of which my code was part. That function is indeed marked as async. (I left it out initially for brevity)

Comment: Good point about the unnecessary promise that wrapped the `setTimeout`. - My intent was to make it wait until the timeout was finished. (which isn't stricly necessary, and which wasn't even working properly).